# Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade - Stopped halfway though

Tags: 14.04

Laptop ran out of battery halfway though upgrade. Fuse blew in charger which I didn't realise until the laptop switched off. Now have a laptop which is half 13.10 and half 14.04 but it says there are no updates to do, therefore how do I upgrade the whole computer?

Comment: Failed upgrades such as you have are difficult to fix. I think you are best off doing a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know the upgrade didn't complete? If the upgrade didn't complete then you would be getting many errors from *apt-get* about unresolved dependencies. The fact that you can boot and it says there are no updates suggests that you upgrade actually completed...

Try *apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade* from a terminal. It will show you which packages still need updating.